# A variant of Cholesky decomposition involving binary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-equations

Studying a problem that is not directly related to linear algebra I came across the following problem.

Let $B$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrix whose entries are non-negative integers. I would like to check whether one can express $B$ as $$B = X X^t \quad (1)$$ where $X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix only having $0$ and $1$ as its entries. Note that $m$ is fixed in this setting.

I can see two necessary conditions for this to be possible

- The eigenvalues of $B$ are not negative
- The element on the $i$'th diagonal of $B$ is $\leq m$ and is the largest element of the $i$'th row and column of $B.$

I am not interested in producing such $X$ itself but rather in finding necessary/sufficient conditions when this is actually possible. Hence

> **Question.** What are some necessary conditions for $B$ to be expressed as in $(1)$?

Comment: This is a discrete problem, so perhaps look at 2x2 and 3x3 matrices, and see if there is some obvious bijection/pattern?

Comment: Is $m$ fixed? If $X$ has an all-ones row than $B$ has a main diagonal entry of $m$, so are you also assuming $m \le n$? Or should the $n$ in your second condition be an $m$?

Comment: @MarkWildon Yes, I think that should actually be a $m.$

Comment: It is still not clear whether you intend $m$ to be fixed or not.

Comment: @MarkWildon I am sorry I have corrected to post to indicate that $m$ is fixed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I'll delete my irrelevant answer in a moment. (But I think the problem with $m$ allowed to vary is also of interest.)

Comment: An obvious but perhaps still useful one is that the diagonal square submatrices of size k have to satisfy the same conditions for kxm matrix products.

Comment: In particular, m >= b_ii +b_jj - b_ij for any indices i and j.

Answer (score 9):

Even the case where $B$ is constant on the diagonal and constant off the diagonal is extremely difficult. For example, it includes the question of for which orders a finite projective plane exists. If I got the numbers right, consider $n=m=157$ and $B$ which is 13 on the diagonal and 1 off the diagonal.  Then $X$ would be a projective plane of order 12, which is a famous unsolved problem. More generally, the existence problem for balanced incomplete block designs can be posed in this way. So it would be exceedingly interesting if an efficiently computable answer to your question existed.